# browserify-shim jquery-validate cannot find module

Tags: browserify-shim

I am trying to use browserify to manage the javascript, but I am blocked at the browserify-shim step.

The structure of my files is:

- build:

  - package.json
  - gulpfaile.js
  - asset_src

    - bower_components

      - jquery-validate

        - dist

          - jquery-validate.js

In package.json I have the following:

```
browserify": {
    "transform": [
        "browserify-shim"
    ]
},
"browser": {
    "jquery": "./asset_src/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js",
    "validator": "./asset_src/bower_components/jquery-validate/dist/jquery.validate.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "validator": {"depends": ["jquery"]}
}
```

And in a module I have:

```
var validator = require("validator");
```

I must be doing something wrong because whenever I use gulp to build, I get a message saying that the module "validator" is not found...

The jquery-validate attaches itself to the jQuery and to the $ on the window object. I have tried quite a few different variants of this, but this seems to be the most correct viewing the documentation... I really don#t know what else to try, so any indication in the right direction would be really apreciated!

All the best,
Gioia

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a solution, but I can tell you that something is going wrong with your shim config. I just circumvented [a similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147775/browserify-require-in-required-file-cannot-find-module) by cutting shim out of it.